# What is the standard size for email greetings cards, birthday cards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a standard, or best practice size for a greeting card you plan on sending **only via email**? I saw one post say as long as the width is below 600px

Comment: I can't really comment on a "standard" size, but is this greeting card intended to be printed? If so, it will probably be printed on a home printer on A4 or Letter paper, so the design should work with those sizes. Either a large half-fold card, or a quarter or tri-fold. Otherwise, it doesn't really matter since it will only be viewed on-screen.

Comment: No, it is specifically designed to be emailed only. That is why I was curious, I wasn't sure if there was a size limitation email providers had.

Comment: As far as technical limitations go, there aren't really any. Design-wise, this problem is pretty much the same as designing any HTML email, so you might have better luck searching for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right.  I'll add a couple of other helpful tips.

The best practice for emails is still to use **XHTML 1.0 Transitional** doctype and create a tabled layout, usually no more than **600px wide**, keeping all HTML styling inline (and avoid shorthand).

Some newer email clients now read the `<style>` tag in your `<head>`, allowing you to use CSS classes and even media queries, to create responsive emails at whatever size you'd like.

These are a few good resources, with much more information on the subject:
http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/
http://templates.mailchimp.com/
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/